# Regex refer to a variable inside a re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm doing practice with regex function in python, but I'm stuck on a problem. Is there a way to refer to a selected part of the string? To be cleaner I want to split the composed hashtag into the main words. For that I'm using a library called "wordninja". So I changed the decode format into wordninja.py file in order to make it understand the latin-1 and changed one of the last string in order to make it split the words, and if I try to split a composed hashtag, it gives me back the main words and in order to do it I wrote a vocabulary in .txt format for the Italian language. For that I'm doing in this way:

```
import wordninja
dic = wordninja.LanguageModel('words_italian_covid.txt.gz')
dic.split('carnesintetica')
>>>['carne', 'sintetica']
```

So the Big idea is to join with a space this split sentence:

```
" ".join(dic.split('carnesintetica'))
>>> carne sintetica
```

For that I want to replace only a part of the selected string doing this manipulation on it. So the word 'carnesintetica' will be the selected part in a re.sub selection, signed as (\w). I give you an example:

```
text1 = '#Coronavirus: ripartiamo dalla Terra.Cosa mangeremo domani? #Food3D, #insetti e #carnesintetica?'
```

I want that the dic.split() operate only on the hashtags selected, that means on the "#Coronavirus", "#Food3D", "#insetti" e "#carnesintetica", in order to obtain "", "<Food 3D>", "", "".
I processed it in this way:

```
import re
text1 = re.sub(r'#(\w+)',r'< \1 >', text1)
```

Then on this string I have the segment problem: I would to operate with dic.split(\1), so only on the selected word, that is to say \1:

```
text1 = re.sub(r'< (\w+) >', ' '.join(dic.split(\w+)), textx1)
```

Here is the problem: I want to know how I could refer to the selected "(\w+)"part in the r'< (\w+) >' inside the dic.split function in order to make the function operate only on the selected word, not on the whole sentence. ?To be cleaner I want operate only with the word inside the two <> symbols, in order to obtain this type of output:

```
'< Coronavirus >: ripartiamo dalla Terra.Cosa mangeremo domani? < Food3D >, < insetti > e < carne sintetica >?'
```

Thank you for the time spent to me and for the patience for my simple question.

Comment: Using match.group(1), try `re.sub(r'#(\w+)', lambda m:f'< {m.group(1)} >', text1)`

Comment: @JasonYang thank you for the answer but in this way where I have to insert the joint function?

Comment: `lambda m:f'< {m.group(1)} >'` is the repl function, you can def a function with join method for it. What's `dic` ?

Comment: @JasonYang thank you, so I try in this way `re.sub(r'< (\w+) >', lambda m:f'< {m.group(" ".join(dic.split((text1))))} >', text1)`, but I have the error "no such group". Maybe I'm doing in the worst way

Comment: Not exactly know what 's your target, maybe like this: `def func(match): return ' '.join(dic.split(m.group(1)))` and `re.sub(r'< (\w+) >', func, text1)`

Comment: " in order to obtain this type of output:", you already got this type of output from top three lines in your code. Are you sure your question is correct ? and what the variable `dic` is ?

Comment: @JasonYang thank you for the answer but I have the error 'str' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: dic is a variable of another package in order to split the words in correct way. I try it and it works as I expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
import wordninja

my_dict = wordninja.LanguageModel('words_italian_covid.txt.gz')

text = '#Coronavirus: ripartiamo dalla Terra.Cosa mangeremo domani? #Food3D, #insetti e #carnesintetica?'

print( re.sub(r'#(\w+)', lambda x: f'< {" ".join(my_dict.split(x.group(1)))} >', text) )

# => < Coronavirus >: ripartiamo dalla Terra.Cosa mangeremo domani? < Food3D >, < insetti > e < carne sintetica >?
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7gBZsC).

The `lambda x: f'< {" ".join(my_dict.split(x.group(1)))} >'` part replaces the match with `< <FOUND_PHRASE_SPLIT_WITH_SPACES >`.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew but the problem is that I can’t define a dictionary for all words because I don’t know what I have to process. For that I will use a tokenization method based on a vocabulary that will split the words in correct way in order to join them. 
I will use wordninja, but I have to do it inside the re function. In my case my_dict is a method of wordninja, that is dict.split(word) and this word I would be the \w inside a re.sub function. Thank you for you’re time and your effort.

Comment: @Jhonny If you need more help, please add all relevant code into the question. This approach is still the answer for the current question.

Comment: I'm sorry but yesterday I wasn't at home. I update my code in the first question. I'm very grateful if you could make me understand how I could do what I would. Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Jhonny I updated with the right code. You do not need to run two `re.sub` here, one will suffice.

Comment: Two re.sub are necessary because without the initial space between the < symbol and the last one, word ninja understand to split for example #carnesintetica word, as one word with # and it processes it with every single letter @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Jhonny `x.group(1)` only contains the part of match *after* `#`, what `(\w+)` captured, so no, not necessary.

Comment: You're great man! @Wiktor Stribiżew thank you for the explanation. I hope my question wasn't too stupid. In this way the code is smoother. I want let you know you're helping me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, thanks to a great help of @Wiktor Stribiżew!
I will share the right code to you:

```
import wordninja
dic = wordninja.LanguageModel('words_italian_covid.txt.gz')
text1 = '#carnesintetica: ripartiamo dalla Terra.\nCosa mangeremo domani? #Food3D, #insetti e #carnesintetica?\nQuesto forzato RESET, ci aiuta a comprendere il vero valore, primario ed essenziale della terra'
import re
text1 = re.sub(r'#(\w+)',r'< \1 >', text1)
text1 = re.sub(r'< (\w+) >', lambda x: f'<{" ".join(dic.split(x.group(1)))}>', text1)
text1
>>> <carne sintetica>: ripartiamo dalla Terra.\nCosa mangeremo domani? <Food 3D>, <insetti> e <carne sintetica>?\nQuesto forzato RESET, ci aiuta a comprendere il vero valore, primario ed essenziale della terra'
```

Thank you a lot. I have only to better understand how the group function operate on the string, if you could suggest me some stuffs in order to do it, I'm very grateful. But I want to say a big thank you to you Wiktor because you helped me a lot!